# Running Selenium RC with maven - having certificate issue for https site

Tags: ssl, maven, selenium, certificate

I am trying to set up automatic java testing with Selenium RC. Since my site is using https, I get an annoying certificate popup that I have to remove before the test starts running. I thought trustAllSSLCertificates combined with *pifirefox would be a good idea and therefore added it to the pom.xml as follows:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <trustAllSSLCertificates>true</trustAllSSLCertificates>
                <firefoxProfileTemplate>C:/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles</firefoxProfileTemplate>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <background>true</background>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

As you can see, I also created a Firefox profile where I added the site. Still it feels like Firefox is not at all running my special profile but a new profile each time. Furthermore, the test is running fine as soon as I add the certificate.

Thanks!
Jay

Comment: Hi there Jay, I highly recommend having a look at [Selenium 2 and Web Driver] (http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html). My team was running into a few different issues using Selenium RC relating to firing up browsers (both headlessly and not). Perhaps this issue has been fixed in Selenium 2?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify the skeleton profile (and have it "small"), Selenium WILL create a new profile.

What I actually did was to create separate firefox profiles and name them according to the certificate used.  I then made the testing code get the appropriate selenium/web driver instance.